# Alternative to lapply that compares all elements with each other? (R, ENMTools)

Tags: r, lapply, raster

I'm trying to compare several species using the R package "ENMTools" and function "enmtools.ecospat.id". Normally you compare two species and the syntax is like this:

```
enmtools.ecospat.id(species1, species2, env[[c("pc1", "pc2")]])
```

where species1 and species2 are the species that will be compared and env points are two variables representing their environment.
Now I would like to compare more than two species, let's say 3, and I would like to compare each species against each one (1 vs 2, 1 vs 3, 2 vs 3). Using the hints on the ENMTools website it is possible use the same function for more than one species - it uses "species.from.file" and "lapply". "species.from.file" works that instead of creating an object for each species it takes a .csv file with many species listed in it so it is not necessary to load every species separately. What I tried was:

```
species.list <- species.from.file("My_species.csv")
my.models <- lapply(species.list, function(x) enmtools.ecospat.id(x, x, env[[c("pc1", "pc2")]]))
```

It works but the problem is that it compares each species with itself (species1 is compared with species1, species2 with species2, and so on) so it doesn't make sense. Is there a way to make a comparison between all possible pairs (so species 1 is compared to 2 and 3, then species 2 to others, and so on).

Another thing is that the output is written as a text and it would be nice to put it into a table or matrix where all the results are stored.

The reproducible example will look like this:

```
library(ENMTools)
library(raster)

#load environmental variables and make PCA
env <- raster::getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
env <- crop(env, extent(-10, 17, 39, 48))
pca <- princomp(na.omit(values(env)), cor=TRUE)
env.pca <- predict(env,pca,index=1:2) 
names(env.pca) <- c("pc1", "pc2")
env.pca <- setMinMax(env.pca)
env.pca <- check.env(env.pca)

#create a species list 
species <- "species Lat Lon
A 41.675507 13.970159
A 42.024733 13.598752
A 42.414286 13.707495
A 42.572775 12.528675
A 42.992760 12.588849
B 42.738985 0.085143
B 42.631137 0.689234
B 42.496283 1.079378
B 42.520370 1.722722
B 42.497944 2.485983
C 44.107110 7.390222
C 44.594351 6.793082
C 45.462129 7.124804
C 46.012260 7.893599
C 46.819861 8.869275
"
species.table <- read.table(text=species, header = TRUE)

##write this into a disk as .csv
write.csv(species.table, file="species.table.csv", append = FALSE, sep = ",", eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

##read back the .csv as a species list
species.list <- species.from.file("species.table.csv")

#let's compare species
my.models <- lapply(species.list, function(x) enmtools.ecospat.id(x, x, env.pca[[c("pc1", "pc2")]]))

#problem - A is compared with A, B with B, and C with C... 
#also the minor problem is that the output is hard to read...
```

I think it is not related to the package itself but requires an alternative to lapply that is not doing comparison in a strict order but compares all elements in the dataset.
I would appreciate any help! Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a million ways to solve that. One option is to learn all the functinos involved, another is to program solutions yourself with very basic functions like `for` loops. Although `for` loops do not have the best reputation in R, they work for many things. I tried to keep this very simple:

```
number_of_columns <- 5
for(i in 1:(number_of_columns - 1))
  for(j in (i+1):number_of_columns)
    print(paste0("compare #", i, " with #", j, " here!"))
```

This will print

```
[1] "compare #1 with #2 here!"
[1] "compare #1 with #3 here!"
[1] "compare #1 with #4 here!"
[1] "compare #1 with #5 here!"
[1] "compare #2 with #3 here!"
[1] "compare #2 with #4 here!"
[1] "compare #2 with #5 here!"
[1] "compare #3 with #4 here!"
[1] "compare #3 with #5 here!"
[1] "compare #4 with #5 here!"
```

Obviously the print-paste call should be replaced by a block calling your function.

To keep results in a nice matrix, you can extend the sample to

```
number_of_columns <- 5
result <- matrix(NA, nrow = number_of_columns -1, ncol = number_of_columns)

for(i in 1:(number_of_columns - 1))
  for(j in (i+1):number_of_columns){
    print(paste0("compare #", i, " with #", j, " here!"))
    result[i, j] <- runif(1)
  }

print(result)
```

where -still for simplicity reasons- I used a call to `runif` instead of your more complicated function call. The resulting matrix `result` might then look like this:

```
> print(result)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]   NA 0.7116926 0.9198481 0.6271107 0.9021818
[2,]   NA        NA 0.7573292 0.1378584 0.1532549
[3,]   NA        NA        NA 0.1913122 0.4331851
[4,]   NA        NA        NA        NA 0.0872193
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still struggling with how to use my function here and I can't find the right example. Specifically how to make that the function will use i and j as input from my species.list? I can't do: enmtools.ecospat.id(i, j, env[[c("pc1", "pc2")]])

Comment: I am not familiar with that package but the function description of `species.from.file` says the return value is "A list containing species objects,..." So you should be able to address the `i`th species as `species.list[[x]]` and the `j`th species as `species.list[[j]]`. I assume something like `enmtools.ecospat.id(species.list[[i]], species.list[[j]], env[[c("pc1", "pc2")]]))` should work.

Comment: Thank you @Bernhard. But I can't figure how to send the results to the matrix or a data frame. When I'm running the function I'm interested in two values $D and $I, and I can acces them by output$test.results$obs$D - I have problem how to send it to external object. When the code is as follows: 
`numspecies = 3
result <- matrix(NA, nrow = numspecies -1, ncol = numspecies)

for(i in 1:(numspecies - 1))
  for(j in (i+1):numspecies)
    enmtools.ecospat.id(species.list[[i]], species.list[[j]], env.pca[[c("pc1", "pc2")]])
    result[i, j] <- output$test.results$obs$D
print(result)`

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer I proposed two `for` loops. Obviously R has a specialized function for you question and that is `combn`.

Let's say you have 5 species and you want to have every combination of 2 of those :

```
species <- c("species 1", "species 2", "species 3", "species 4", "species 5")
combn(species, m = 2)
```

This will give you an array in which every column stands for one combination:

```
> combn(species, m = 2)
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]       
[1,] "species 1" "species 1" "species 1" "species 1" "species 2" "species 2"
[2,] "species 2" "species 3" "species 4" "species 5" "species 3" "species 4"
     [,7]        [,8]        [,9]        [,10]      
[1,] "species 2" "species 3" "species 3" "species 4"
[2,] "species 5" "species 4" "species 5" "species 5"
```

Advantages are that you can avoid `for` loops if you mind about that and use the `apply` family as in

```
species <- c("species 1", "species 2", "species 3", "species 4", "species 5")
combinations <- combn(species, m = 2)
apply(combinations, 2, function(x){
    cat("\ncompare "); cat(x[1]); cat(" with "); cat(x[2])
  }
)
```

The obvious advantage of `combn` comes into play when you need combinations of more then two species. You can do `combn(species, 4)` without nesting arbitrary many loops.